# spell out the direction of a street name

Tags: r, regex

I tried to correct the street names of a data frame using stringr package, spelling out "S." to "South" or "E" to "East" as well as "st." to "Street". The sample data is below.

```
df = data.frame(street = c('333 S. HOPE STREET', '21 South Hope Street', '54 Hope PKWY', '60C/O St.'))
```

This is my code.

```
  df2 <- df %>% mutate(street2 = str_replace(street, 'S', "South"),
                     street2 = str_replace_all(street2, 'PKWY', "PARKWAY"),
                     street2 = str_replace_all(street2, 'st.', "Street"))
```

It returns to the following result.

```
street              street2

333 S. HOPE STREET     333 South. HOPE STREET
21 South Hope Street   21 Southouth Hope Street
54 Hope PKWY           54 Hope PARKWAY
60C/O St.              60C/O Southt.
```

This is the result I desire. Not sure where I get wrong.

```
street              street2

333 S. HOPE STREET     333 South HOPE STREET
21 South Hope Street   21 South Hope Street
54 Hope PKWY           54 Hope PARKWAY
60C/O St.              60C/O Sreet.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to escape the dots! In a regex-pattern, the `.` matches (almost) any character. If you mean a literal dot, you have to escape the dot, with a `\` (which you also have to escape with another `\`).

So:

```
df %>% mutate(street2 = str_replace(street, 'S\\.', "South"),
                     street2 = str_replace_all(street2, 'PKWY', "PARKWAY"),
                     street2 = str_replace_all(street2, 'St\\.', "Street"))
```

will result in

```
#                 street               street2
# 1   333 S. HOPE STREET 333 South HOPE STREET
# 2 21 South Hope Street  21 South Hope Street
# 3         54 Hope PKWY       54 Hope PARKWAY
# 4            60C/O St.          60C/O Street
```

and for better readable results, you can use `stringr::str_to_title`

```
df %>% mutate(street2 = str_replace(street, 'S\\.', "South"),
              street2 = str_replace_all(street2, 'PKWY', "PARKWAY"),
              street2 = str_replace_all(street2, 'St\\.', "Street") ) %>%
  mutate_all( ., str_to_title )

#                 street               street2
# 1   333 S. Hope Street 333 South Hope Street
# 2 21 South Hope Street  21 South Hope Street
# 3         54 Hope Pkwy       54 Hope Parkway
# 4            60c/O St.          60c/O Street
```